# What is the fastest way to reduce elements of a list by frequency?

Tags: r, list

Suppose that I have a list similar to this one:

```
set.seed(12731)
out <- lapply(1:sample.int(10, 1), function(x){sample(letters[1:4], x, replace = T)})

[[1]]
[1] "b"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "c"

[[3]]
[1] "b" "a" "a"

[[4]]
[1] "d" "d" "b" "c"

[[5]]
[1] "d" "d" "c" "c" "b"

[[6]]
[1] "b" "d" "b" "d" "c" "c"

[[7]]
[1] "a" "b" "d" "d" "b" "a" "d"
```

I would like to have vectors of length one given by the element of higher frequency in the list. Notice that ***is possible to have vectors of length > 1 if there are no duplicates***. The frequency table is like this:

```
table(unlist(out))[order(table(unlist(out)), decreasing = T)]

 b  c  d  a 
16 14 13 12
```

The outcome of the example is something like this:

```
list("b", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
```

**REMARK**
It is possible to have vectors of length > 1 if there are no duplicates.

```
out <- lapply(1:sample.int(10, 1), function(x){sample(letters[1:4], x, replace = T)})
length(out)
[1] 10
out[[length(out)+1]] <- c("L", "K")
out
[[1]]
[1] "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "a"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "b" "a"

[[4]]
[1] "b" "c" "b" "c"

[[5]]
[1] "a" "a" "d" "c" "d"

[[6]]
[1] "d" "b" "d" "d" "d" "a"

[[7]]
[1] "d" "b" "c" "c" "d" "c" "a"

[[8]]
[1] "d" "a" "d" "b" "d" "a" "b" "d"

[[9]]
[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "c" "d"

[[10]]
 [1] "d" "d" "d" "a" "d" "d" "c" "c" "a" "c"

[[11]]
[1] "L" "K"
```

Expected outcome:

```
list("c", "d", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", c("L", "K"))
```

Comment: You need to `set.seed`

Comment: TX, you mean that to make the example clearer right?

Comment: And to make it reproducible so that everyone trying to solve can work on the same set of data and compare solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't you have 7 elements in the output vector since you have 7 elements in the list?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the expected outcome should have the same length as the input list. I corrected that, it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Arguable dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode

Comment: @Frank. I think it's more complicated. The OP wants to 1 Calculate the frequency of distinct elements across all list items (which includes the mode) 2 Find the element within each list item that has the highest frequency count calculated by 1. 3 also take account of ties.

Comment: @lmo It looks like `lapply(List, Mode, ties="all")` for some mode function with that option. To me, `lapply(List, f)` is not really a different q from how to make `f`.

Comment: @Frank But it's not the mode of each individual list item (vector) that is relevant, but rather the frequency ranking (mode) of the entire unlisted vector, `unlist(List)` in your example. Then, values are pulled out of each list item based on this ranking.

Comment: @lmo Ok. I guess it's more complicated/hard to understand than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this should work for what you are looking for.

```
# get counts for entire list and order them
myRanks <- sort(table(unlist(out)), decreasing=TRUE)
```

This produces

```
myRanks

 b  c  d  a 
10  9  5  4 


# calculate if most popular, then second most popular, ... item shows up for each list item
sapply(out, function(i) names(myRanks)[min(match(i, names(myRanks)))])
[1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

Here, `sapply` runs through each list item and returns a vector. It applies a function that selects the name of the first element (via `min`) of the myRanks table that appears in the list element, using `match`.

---

In the case of multiple elements having the same count (duplicates) in the myRanks table, the following code should to return a list of the top observations per list item:

```
sapply(out,
     function(i) {
       intersect(names(myRanks)[myRanks == max(unique(myRanks[match(i, names(myRanks))]))],
                 i)})
```

Here, the names of myRanks that have the same value as the value in the list item with the highest value in myRanks are intersected with the names present in the list item in order to only return values in both sets.

Comment: I really like your answer is clean, but could you please read my remark.

Comment: I managed to do it like this too: 
myRanks <- sort(table(unlist(out)), decreasing=TRUE)
sapply(out, function(i){inter <- myRanks [intersect(i, names(myRanks))]
names(which(inter==max(inter))) } )

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
set.seed(12731)
out <- lapply(1:sample.int(10, 1), function(x){sample(letters[1:4], x, replace = T)})
out
#[[1]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "c" "b"

#[[3]]
#[1] "b" "b" "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "d" "c" "c" "d"

#[[5]]
#[1] "d" "b" "a" "a" "c"

#[[6]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "c"

#[[7]]
#[1] "a" "c" "d" "b" "d" "c" "b"

tbl <- table(unlist(out))[order(table(unlist(out)), decreasing = T)]
sapply(out, function(x) intersect(names(tbl), x)[1])
# [1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

**[EDIT]**

```
set.seed(12731)
out <- lapply(1:sample.int(10, 1), function(x){sample(letters[1:4], x, replace = T)})
out[[length(out)+1]] <- c("L", "K")
out
#[[1]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "c" "b"

#[[3]]
#[1] "b" "b" "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "d" "c" "c" "d"

#[[5]]
#[1] "d" "b" "a" "a" "c"

#[[6]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "c"

#[[7]]
#[1] "a" "c" "d" "b" "d" "c" "b"

#[[8]]
#[1] "L" "K"

tbl <- table(unlist(out))[order(table(unlist(out)), decreasing = T)]

#tbl
#b  c  d  a  K  L 
#10  9  5  4  1  1 

lapply(out, function(x) names(tbl[tbl==max(tbl[names(tbl) %in%  intersect(names(tbl), x)])]))

#[[1]]
#[1] "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

#[[3]]
#[1] "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "c"

#[[5]]
#[1] "b"

#[[6]]
#[1] "b"

#[[7]]
#[1] "b"

#[[8]]
#[1] "K" "L"
```

Comment: TX, but this is not what I meant. The frequency has to be calculated with all the elements of the list, not single elements. Just the way I computed it in the example.

Comment: This is almost what I expected, could you please read my remark?